# How to display a perfect background image

Tags: html, image

I have to make a website but i have some problem to display my background image

I don't know ho to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these properties to your CSS/HTML

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
```